# Extra horizontal space with forest and standalone pacakage

Tags: forest, standalone

I created some style files for standalone pictures. However, I get unwanted horizontal space.

Here is my first MWE1:

```
\documentclass[convert={true,convertexe={magick.exe},
   command=\unexpanded{{\convertexe\space -density \density\space \infile\space \ifx\size\empty\else -resize \size\fi\space \outfile}}}]{standalone}

\RequirePackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
[ 2 [1] [3]]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image: MWE1]

However, I want to change my transparent background. Here is MWE2:

```
\documentclass[convert={true,convertexe={magick.exe},
   command=\unexpanded{{\convertexe\space -density \density\space \infile\space \ifx\size\empty\else -resize \size\fi\space -transparent white'rgb(100,200,100)' \outfile}}}]{standalone}

\RequirePackage{forest}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\definecolor{tr}{RGB}{100,200,100}
\pagecolor{tr}

\begin{forest}
[ 2 [1] [3]]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image: MWE2]

Notice the extra horizontal space before the tree. This is just a MWE, so it is not a lot. However, with bigger trees, the space gets bigger:

[image: MWE3]

Does anyone have an idea to get rid of this?

Comment: Welcome! Add percentage signs: `\definecolor{tr}{RGB}{100,200,100}%` and 
`\pagecolor{tr}%`. You may also just move `\begin{document}` after `\pagecolor{tr}`.

Comment: Which TeX distribution are you using and is it current?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Can you test `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={circle,draw}
  [1[2[3][4]][5]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}`? Do you get an error?

Comment: @cfr I do: `dimension too large`.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Weird, isn't it? There's no error with Texlive 2018, even though `forest.sty` is identical. (I may not have the last updates to reach TL2018, so it could be it works for some point in TL2018 and not later.) Thanks for checking.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/513716/what-is-the-cause-of-this-dimension-too-large-error-occurs-with-tl2019-but-not @Schrödinger'scat <at> anyone.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat `forest` is definitely adding spurious space, too. Non-answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/514047/. Does anything look suspicious to you in the two lines I've marked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to place the settings before `\begin{document}`

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{tr}{RGB}{100,200,100}
\pagecolor{tr}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
[ 2 [1] [3]]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, `forest` has the tendency to add space; an easy workaround is to call `standalone` with the `varwidth` option.

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}

\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{tr}{RGB}{100,200,100}
\pagecolor{tr}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  [A[B[D][E]][C[F][G]]]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Compare with the output one gets without `varwidth`:

[image]

## General solution

The spaces are added because of an unprotected end of line in the definition of `\pgfutilsolvetwotwoleqfloat` in `pgfutil-common.tex`, precisely at the end of line 712

```
712                 \edef\pgf@marshal{
713                     \noexpand\pgfmathfloatdivide@
714                         {\csname r\Pb\endcsname}
715                         {\csname m\Pb b\endcsname}%
716                 }%
```

Indeed, if I do

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
% remove the stray space
\patchcmd{\pgfutilsolvetwotwoleqfloat}
  { \noexpand\pgfmathfloatdivide@}
  {\noexpand\pgfmathfloatdivide@}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  [A[B[D][E]][C[F][G]]]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

the result is correct as expected

[image]

Thanks to cfr who was able to circumscribe the problem. See the issue report at https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/764

Comment: This doesn't solve the general problem which is that space is being added inside the `forest` environment. It does not happen with all trees, including the one here, but it happens with many (most?). That is, this solves the problem for the first tree, but not the second.

Comment: @cfr Now I saw the issue, with a different `forest`. The workaround is using `varwidth`.

Comment: @cfr Found, it's `pgf`'s fault, not `forest`'s.

Comment: Fantastic! Schrödinger's cat and I were trying to pinpoint it below, but I, at least, was not getting much beyond the `intersections` library.

Comment: It was a long time ago since I posted this problem. Sorry for not responding. Thank you for your investigation and solution!

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an answer, but an attempt to point towards the problem.
`forest` **is** adding space, as the following example shows:

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[]{forest}
\forestset{
  pack stage/.style={TeX=a,for root'=pack,TeX=b}
}
\begin{document}
\fbox{\begin{forest}
  [A[B[D][E]][C[F][G]]]
\end{forest}}
\end{document}
```

[image: spurious space with Forest]

The problem can be traced to the following lines in `forest.sty`:

```
  \pgfintersectionofpaths{\pgfsetpath\forest@all@edges}{\pgfsetpath\forest@node@edge}%
  \def\forest@edgenode@intersections{}%
```

Adding markers as follows

```
  X\pgfintersectionofpaths{\pgfsetpath\forest@all@edges}{\pgfsetpath\forest@node@edge}%
  Y\def\forest@edgenode@intersections{}%
```

shows the culprit is somewhere here

[image: culprit between X and Y]

However, I'm not sure how to debug this further, so posting this in the hope somebody else may be able to follow the trail from here.

Comment: Naively one may think it shouldn't come from the `\pgfsetpath` because it is used all over and does not *seem* to produce spaces. But this could be wrong since in `tikzpicture`s these spaces would be gobbled anyway. This leads to the question how on earth the problem can arise because I thought a forest tree *is* a `tikzpicture`. Does forest have a "survey phase" before it starts the actual `tikzpicture`?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Yes. At least, I think so. It works in `stages` and I don't think they're all inside `tikzpicture`. I've seen Forest add spurious spaces before, but I think this one is at lines 168/169 of `pgflibraryintersections.code.tex`. At least, if I put markers on those lines, I catch the spaces between.

Comment: Yes. I think to have ruled out `\pgfsetpath` , which is northing but `\pgfsyssoftpath@setcurrentpath` which gets defined in `pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex`, and seems to be clean.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat In fact, you can change the `tikzpicture` environment to something else, if you want to. It is only used in the final stage, when the tree is actually drawn (or saved into a box, if you choose that option). Before that, we have all the other `stages`. `prooftrees` has even more :(.

Comment: I was hoping that the old `pgfplotsoldpgfsupp_pgflibraryintersections.code.tex` would not have the problem, but no. So one real possibility is that in the very tiny ecosystem of Ti*k*Z somewhere there is a spurious space that went mostly unnoticed so far because the respective macro was mostly used inside a `tikzpicture` environment, where it does not have an effect. Searching for a needle in a haystack might be fun in comparison... :-(

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat But `forest` have to have not noticed as well and this space seems awfully easy to trigger.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Version 1 includes `\usepgflibrary{intersections}`, so my guess is that, yes, Forest always used them. I don't know about the `fpu` thing in `intersections`, though.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Yes, that's line 168. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/513491/extra-horizontal-space-with-forest-and-standalone-pacakage/514047?noredirect=1#comment1299930_514047

Comment: It is really weird. If I add a `{}` after the `\pgf@intersect@next` at the very end of `\def\pgf@intersectionofpaths`, i.e. in line 237 of  `pgflibraryintersections.code.tex` the issue is gone. BUT I am more than just a bit worried that this will break something. I do not have any understanding for the flip-flop between `\pgfutil@firstoftwo` and `\pgfutil@secondoftwo` in its redefinitions.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat The problem is **not** there if I compile with Texlive 2017 ...

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Or Texlive 2018 (which has identical `forest.sty` to TL 2019). So it is something relatively recent.

Comment: Well, given all the troubles with `intersections`, i.e. here and your recent question, the problem may be there. (I only have one TeX installation so I cannot check.)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat See egreg's comment above: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/513491/extra-horizontal-space-with-forest-and-standalone-pacakage/514047?noredirect=1#comment1300036_513549. ;)

Comment: I actually have an unrelated question I wanted to ask since you were writing packages for trees. Have you ever isolated the sorting machinery of forest? That is, do you know something that is fast, does not load all the expl3 overhead, and allows me to sort lists? Or, even better, to sort lists in which each entry is a list, i.e. arrays, by the first entry of each sublist, say?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I'm not sure what you have in mind, but I only wrote `prooftrees`. `forest` got adapted a bit, spurred by `prooftrees`, but I only know the user-level stuff. `prooftrees` uses `forest`'s sorting, but that's about it. (I'm only sorting nodes - not content.) You should ask Sašo about the internal stuff. However `forest` and 'fast' are not generally words one would think of together. The `pgfmath` stuff is s-s-l-l-o-o-w-w. The argument processor, which uses TeX instead, is fast. But the overall result is generally slow. You could look at `forest`'s `index` stuff?

Answer (score 0):

I want to add an answer for anyone with a recent TeXlive (in my case 2022) who comes across this question and still gets horizontal space. Use case is for defining commands for that `standalone` file that are not needed in the main document that the `standalone` is being `\includestandalone{}`'ed into to. Comments are required at the end of every line after `\begin{document}` regardless of whether it is necessary in normal LaTeX. For example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\definecolor{tr}{RGB}{100,200,100}
\pagecolor{tr}
\tikzset{%
    dotted_block/.style={draw=red!70!white, line width=0.5pt, dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt,
            inner ysep=0pt,inner xsep=-2pt, rectangle, rounded corners}%
}
\begin{forest}
[ 2 [1] [3]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

produces:

[image]

whereas with comments at the end of every line after `\begin{document}`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\definecolor{tr}{RGB}{100,200,100}%
\pagecolor{tr}%
\tikzset{%
    dotted_block/.style={draw=red!70!white, line width=0.5pt, dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt,%
            inner ysep=0pt,inner xsep=-2pt, rectangle, rounded corners}%
}%
\begin{forest}
[ 2 [1] [3]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

produces:

[image]

I could not find a reference to this and searching within the [`forest` documentation on CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/forest) for "space" and "comment" didn't turn up this advice so maybe it will be helpful to others.