# Formating nodes' content depending on parameters

Tags: tikz-trees, forest, trees

I would like to be able to change the **content** of the nodes, from a home made parameter list to an actual text.

For example, I would like to create trees such as:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
[9;12;4
    [31;21]
    [3
        [14]
        [7;21;3]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

will be formatted this way:

[image]

Basically, depending on the number of parameters, separated by a semi-column, I would like to format the final content differently:

- with 1 parameter, format is "#1 is the one"
- with 2 parameters, format is "with #1[#2]"
- with 3 parameters, format is "$#2 \geq #1$ for #3 cases"

So far, I managed to split the content of each node with **split option**, but I did not succeed to know how many I actually have, and access each of them.

What I am looking for is something like:

```latex
before typesetting nodes={
   for tree={
       split option={content}{;}{params},
       if {length(params) = 1}{content=params[1] is the one}{
           if {length(params) = 2}{content=with params[1][params[2]]}{
               if {length(params} = 3}{content=$params[2] \geq params[1]$ for params[3] cases}
               {}
            }
        }  
    }
}
```

PS: The reason I am trying to do that in such way it's because I need to create a lot of big trees with the same node format.
And from a writer perspective, it is much easier to just chose the parameters of each nodes and keep the formatting separated, especially if you have to change it later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`split option` (and other `split` keys) "zip" the given "instruction" keylist (their `#3`) and the "parameter" list (in the option case, the split value of the option given as their `#1`). The parts of the option can thus be processed by different keys.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\forestset{
  declare toks register=param1,
  declare toks register=param2,
  declare toks register=param3,
  gobble/.style={},
  my split/.style={
    param1={},
    param2={},
    param3={},
    split option={content}{;}{param1,param2,param3,gobble},
    if param2={}{
      content'/.process=Rw1{param1}{##1 is the one}
    }{
      if param3={}{
        content'/.process=R2w2{param1}{param2}{with ##1[##2]}
      }{
        content'/.process=R3w3{param1}{param2}{param3}{$##2 \geq ##1$ for ##3 cases}
      }
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest} delay={for tree=my split}
[9;12;4
    [31;21]
    [3
        [14]
        [7;21;3]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if `split option` works with lists of different dimensions. (I am not sure really means that I do not know.) However, you could split the contents with `xstring`. (I also added a [patch that removes spurious spaces](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/513549); in later versions of pgf this will no longer be needed.)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{xstring}
\makeatletter
% remove the stray space https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/513549
\patchcmd{\pgfutilsolvetwotwoleqfloat}
  { \noexpand\pgfmathfloatdivide@}
  {\noexpand\pgfmathfloatdivide@}
  {}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
before typesetting nodes={
    for tree={
        content/.wrap value={\StrCount{#1}{;}[\mydim]%
        \StrSubstitute{#1}{;}{,}[\mytemp]%
        \ifcase\mydim
         \pgfmathsetmacro{\myone}{{\mytemp}[0]}\myone\ is the one
        \or
         \pgfmathsetmacro{\myone}{{\mytemp}[0]}%
         \pgfmathsetmacro{\mytwo}{{\mytemp}[1]}%
         {with \myone[\mytwo]}
        \or
         \pgfmathsetmacro{\myone}{{\mytemp}[0]}%
         \pgfmathsetmacro{\mytwo}{{\mytemp}[1]}%
         \pgfmathsetmacro{\mythree}{{\mytemp}[2]}%
         {$\mytwo\geq\myone$ for \mythree\ cases}
        \fi}}}
[9;12;4
    [31;21]
    [3
        [14]
        [7;21;3]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or a version that works with strings, too.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{xstring}
\makeatletter
% remove the stray space https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/513549
\patchcmd{\pgfutilsolvetwotwoleqfloat}
  { \noexpand\pgfmathfloatdivide@}
  {\noexpand\pgfmathfloatdivide@}
  {}{}
\makeatother
\def\pfttwo#1;#2|{\def\myone{#1}\def\mytwo{#2}}%
\def\pftthree#1;#2;#3|{\def\myone{#1}\def\mytwo{#2}\def\mythree{#3}}%
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
before typesetting nodes={
    for tree={
        content/.wrap value={\StrCount{#1}{;}[\mydim]%
        \ifcase\mydim
         \pgfmathsetmacro{\myone}{#1}\myone\ is the one
        \or
         \pfttwo#1|%
         {with \myone[\mytwo]}
        \or
         \pftthree#1|%
         {$\mytwo\geq\myone$ for \mythree\ cases}
        \fi}}}
[9;12;4
    [31;21]
    [3
        [14]
        [7;21;3]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Any extras go to the last thing, so you can process a list of n items with a parsing list of one and all n will be sent, one after the other, to the one. (Which is a very confusing way of saying it.)