# Extra space on the left of Forest tree

Tags: spacing, forest

I made a wide tree with Forest and I want use `resizebox` to scale it down to match the text length. I noticed that the space on the left of the tree is oddly bigger, specially if compared to the space on the right. How I can fix it?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

Some text
\begin{center}
        \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
            \fbox{             
                \begin{forest}
                    for tree = {l sep = 20 mm}
                    [Root
                        [A long label for a inner node
                            [A long label for a leaf]
                            [A long label for a leaf]
                        ]
                        [A long label for a inner node
                            [A long label for a leaf]
                            [A long label for a leaf]
                        ]
                        [A long label for a inner node
                            [A long label for a leaf]
                            [A long label for a leaf]
                        ]
                        [A long label for a inner node
                            [A long label for a leaf]
                            [A long label for a leaf]
                        ]
                    ]
                \end{forest}
            }
        }
\end{center}
other text.

\end{document}
```

Here is the output:[image]

Comment: Welcome! Did you update your installation recently? There was a bug that added space, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/513491/194703), but it got fixed. So you may want to update your installation.

Comment: you are adding space with `\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{SPACE \fbox{SPACE ` but as far as I can see you are adding two at each end so that doesn't really account for the asymmetry

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Do you get the same space as the OP when you compile the code? I do not, and I do think it could be [this bug](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/513491/194703).

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat no extra space on the left in tl2018/tl2019/tl2020

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, this is consistent (to the best of my knowledge). At a given point in 2019 `forest` got updated, and used a pgf function that had spurious spaces in. Later the bug in the pgf function got fixed. So I think that if you have versions only before the `forest` update or after the pgf update, you won't see these spaces. The simplest way to test this could be that Fabio tries out the patch under the link and checks whether the spaces go away.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat if only it had used picture mode not pgf:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Or just a black bar instead of a forest? This would be a very futuristic forest, after all trees are gone.

Comment: I confirm that the bug is the one linked by @Schrödinger'scat and the patch is working. I am using Overleaf so I can't update my installation but as far as the patch is working I don't mid.

Answer (score 3):

A hack: write this after loading `forest`.

```
\makeatletter
\preto\forest@pack{\nullfont}
\makeatother
```

This makes `forest` switch to the null font before starting to pack. (Packing is the heart of `forest`, where the positions of nodes are computed. There's a lot of computation going on there. In particular, a lot of line intersections are computed, using PGF's machinery, and this is where we typically get the leaking spaces.)

While the hack eats up the leaking spaces, it introduces an empty line (maybe a paragraph break?) on top of `\fbox`. I don't know why precisely this happens (I hope somebody can explain). A hack within hack is to add the comment signs at the beginning of `\resizebox` and `\fbox` arguments -- this removes the space tokens.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{forest}

\makeatletter
\preto\forest@pack{\nullfont}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Some text
\begin{center}
        \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{% without these comments
            \fbox{% we get some extra vertical space
                \begin{forest}
                    for tree = {l sep = 20 mm}
                    [Root
                        [A long label for a inner node
                            [A long label for a leaf]
                            [A long label for a leaf]
                        ]
                        [A long label for a inner node
                            [A long label for a leaf]
                            [A long label for a leaf]
                        ]
                        [A long label for a inner node
                            [A long label for a leaf]
                            [A long label for a leaf]
                        ]
                        [A long label for a inner node
                            [A long label for a leaf]
                            [A long label for a leaf]
                        ]
                    ]
                \end{forest}
            }
        }
\end{center}
other text.

\end{document}
```

Note that while the hack works in this particular example, it will not do in general. It is sure to fail if you use `typeset node` after packing, because the null font is still in effect.

If I manage to iron out these kinks, I might even consider integrating it into `forest` itself -- after all, it is inavoidable that some future version of PGF will introduce some new leaking spaces ...

Answer (score 1):

Better than make note text unreadable with scaling of `forest` tree diagram is consider to rotate it with `grow=east` and (if the nodes text is really long) enables nodes' texts to break into more lines. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

Some text
\begin{center}
\fbox{
    \begin{forest}
        for tree = {
        font=\small,
        grow'=east,
        child anchor=west,
        l sep = 12 mm,
        s sep =2mm,
        where level = {0}{}{text width=width("A long label ")}
                    }
        [Root
            [A long label for a inner node
                [A long label for a leaf]
                [A long label for a leaf]
            ]
            [A long label for a inner node
                [A long label for a leaf]
                [A long label for a leaf]
            ]
            [A long label for a inner node
                [A long label for a leaf]
                [A long label for a leaf]
            ]
            [A long label for a inner node
                [A long label for a leaf]
                [A long label for a leaf]
            ]
        ]
    \end{forest}
}
\end{center}
other text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, does it? If the OP has a TeX installation from a certain period, it will still have the spaces in.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! My real labels have different wides and I would like have something like tier=word for horizontal layout. Do you or @Schrödinger's cat how to do that (maybe I should open a new question)?

Comment: @FabioT. No one knows these things better than Sašo Živanović.

Comment: @Sašo Živanović can you help me?

Comment: @FabioT., You have his answer below ...